# Order by multiple OR Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have this Query that I want to return in a specific order

```
SELECT idperson, name
FROM movie.people
WHERE idperson LIKE '23'
OR idperson LIKE '1'
OR idperson LIKE '24'
OR idperson LIKE '25'
OR idperson LIKE '26'
OR idperson LIKE '27'
OR idperson LIKE '28'
OR idperson LIKE '29'
```

Is there a way that I can return the result in order of LIKE, OR, OR, OR and so on? Or attach some value to the LIKE and OR as a 'order by column'?

The resultcolumn I want is in this example

23, 1, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29.

Comment: add: **ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(idperson,'23,1,24,25,26,27,28,29');**  , but i dont understand why you use **LIKE** in your query. There is no % in your strings

Comment: Why all these `LIKE '1'....` and not `= '1'...`?

Comment: "but i dont understand why you use LIKE". It has worked for everything I have done so far, but I guess I should start using = instead when no % are required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the hole query:

```
SELECT idperson, name
FROM movie.people
WHERE idperson LIKE '23'
OR idperson LIKE '1'
OR idperson LIKE '24'
OR idperson LIKE '25'
OR idperson LIKE '26'
OR idperson LIKE '27'
OR idperson LIKE '28'
OR idperson LIKE '29'
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(idperson,'23,1,24,25,26,27,28,29');
```

Comment: Improvement: `idperson IN (...)`?

Comment: @marvin  - FIND_IN_SET(..,..) returns the position of found number. so you can order with it

Comment: Yes, but that wasn't my point ;) The multiple `OR` clauses and the `LIKE` seem unelegant. Although not directly related to the question, it seems like an obvious improvement. Still a valid answer, though.

Answer (score 2):

You could just add a case to the order by statement and assign sorting values depending on the LIKE match (although it seems very tedious)

```
SELECT idperson, name
FROM movie.people
WHERE idperson LIKE '23'
OR idperson LIKE '1'
OR idperson LIKE '24'
OR idperson LIKE '25'
OR idperson LIKE '26'
OR idperson LIKE '27'
OR idperson LIKE '28'
OR idperson LIKE '29'
ORDER BY
CASE
    WHEN idperson LIKE '23' THEN 1
    WHEN idperson LIKE '1' THEN 2
    WHEN idperson LIKE '24' THEN 3
    -- And so on...
END
```

Also you could improve your query by using the [`IN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) operator and rewrite your query like

```
idperson IN ('23', '1', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29')
```

Note: The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55249732/4569506) by [Bernd Buffen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5247279/bernd-buffen) to use `FIND_IN_SET()` is a probably a better way to do this

Comment: *"Note: The answer by Bernd Buffen to use FIND_IN_SET() is a probably a better way to do this"* Depends if you want database vendor portable code this is the way to go..

Comment: Was unfamiliar with the IN operator, been looking for "it" but never put much though to it. I ended up using that aswell as Bernd's suggested "FIND_IN_SET()". It does indeed make the query more elegant (as it was pointed out as unelegant in a comment above :))